# how to get values from checkboxlist on popup to use parent page?

Tags: java, javascript, checkbox, popup, struts

i develop java struts framework. I want that, when i select some values from checkboxlist on popup page, get from all values that selected checkboxlist to using on parent page. my purpose is getting person names on popup page and fill list with this values on parent page

i can open popup and fill checkboxlist(popup) with value but next don t know?

Thanx to reply

Answer (score 0):

This is a common javascript functionality. Please check the link [This link gives generic steps for passing values from a child popup to the parent page.](http://hspinfo.wordpress.com/2008/01/17/javascript-send-pass-value-of-child-window-to-parent-window/)